# Unable to connect to keyserver to import MongoDB installation public key

Tags: software-installation

I am very new to ubuntu.
I am trying to install MongoDB on AWS using ubuntu but have been having problem connecting to the keyserver to import the public key.
I tried many suggestions offered here and elsewhere but to no avail. I have switched off my firewalls also but still no success.

Comment: Have you tried this one?  https://askubuntu.com/a/842599/231142

Comment: I solved my problem. I was connected to the wrong region. It works after I created a new instance in the correction region.