# Kubuntu 18.04 upgrade has broken MongoDB server?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, mongodb

It seems that after upgrading to Ubuntu/ Kubuntu 18.04 has broken my MongoDB server.

I have tried to reinstall Mongo but I still can't start it as before:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

The status:

```
$ sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-10-07 14:30:40 BST; 17s ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
  Process: 5925 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=${SOCKETPATH} --config ${CONF} $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=62)
 Main PID: 5925 (code=exited, status=62)

Oct 07 14:30:38 lau-desktop systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Oct 07 14:30:40 lau-desktop systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=62/n/a
Oct 07 14:30:40 lau-desktop systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

When I tried to install mongo 4, I get the error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.0.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
$ mongo --versionMongoDB shell version v4.0.3
git version: 7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

$ sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-10-07 15:12:14 BST; 1h 7min ago
 Main PID: 2232 (code=exited, status=62)

Oct 07 15:12:13 lau-desktop systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Oct 07 15:12:14 lau-desktop systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=62/n/a
Oct 07 15:12:14 lau-desktop systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Maybe this might help?  https://askubuntu.com/a/842599/231142

Comment: @Terrance still the same... no luck at all :(

Comment: Maybe try running `sudo apt clean` to clean the cache folder then try the install again.

Comment: @Terrance thanks but still no luck. please see my edit above.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Probably need to remove the previous version before installing the new one. I am sorry I didn't think about that.  Before removing the old version try running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and maybe see if it upgrades to the 4.0 which is supposed to be for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Terrance please see my edit 2. I think I should remove all the broken .dev. how can I remove them?

Comment: @Terrance I think I have it installed ok now but it still fails to start. see my edit 3. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) from Mongo official site, I got it fixed.

Step 1:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E52529D4
```

Step 2:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

Step 3:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 4:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.0.2 mongodb-org-server=4.0.2 mongodb-org-shell=4.0.2 mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.2 mongodb-org-tools=4.0.2
```

Step 5:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Step 6:

```
sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-10-07 17:06:28 BST; 4min 24s ago
 Main PID: 27797 (mongod)
    Tasks: 26 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─27797 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

Oct 07 17:06:28 lau-desktop systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Oct 07 17:06:28 lau-desktop mongod[27797]: 2018-10-07T17:06:28.337+0100 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

Comment: +1 Glad you found a way to fix the dilemma you were having.  =)  You can accept your own answer here.

Comment: AWESOME!  This worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. The accepted answer did not worked for me, as I was trying to install version `4.0.5`. I like to share how I solved the problem.

From the error message, I learnt that, apt is trying overwrite `/usr/bin/bsondump` of version `3.6.3`, with the latest version(at the time of writing this) `4.0.5`. Earlier, I did removed, previously install mongodb version `3.6.3`. Some how, `mongo-tools` package was left.

So, I simply needed to remove `mongo-tools@3.6.3`. But, as the installation of `mongodb@4.0.5` did not completed successfully, I had to reset `apt` before, I can do anything with `apt`.

This command undid the broken package installation.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org
```

Then, I simply ran following commands to remove `mongo-tools@3.6.3`

```
sudo apt update # to refresh apt
sudo apt remove mongo-tools # to remove mongo-tools 3.6.3
```

Finally, I re-ran the following command to install latest mongodb

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

It worked!