# Mongodb don't start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mongodb

I don't know why this is happening.

I have installed mongodb but It is not starting. I have resinstall many times with not success: here is the error when I check  mongo status:

```
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-10-07 17:01:43 CEST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
  Process: 18564 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=62)
 Main PID: 18564 (code=exited, status=62)

Okt 07 17:01:43 user systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Okt 07 17:01:43 user systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=62/n/a
Okt 07 17:01:43 user systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can you help me to solve this ?

Comment: Maybe try https://askubuntu.com/a/842599/231142 where I have the MongoDB 4.0 for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Could you provide more info. At least version of mongodb, ...

Answer (score 3):

Status 62 means you have too new of Mongo installed for the DB files that are present on the host. You can downgrade Mongo and then upgrade back up in stages to keep the data, dump out the data and restore it, or delete it and start fresh.

Comment: I also got the status=62/n/a error from the other way around. I downgraded from Mongo 6 to Mongo 5 and needed to clear out the data folder that was populated with files from Mongo 6 before Mongo 5 would start.