# Failing to install MongoDB on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, database, mongodb

Trying to install the community version of mongo on ubuntu 18.04.

Below are my unsuccessful attempts , if you don't have time - just go directly to the result in attempt #3.

***Attempt #1***

Using offical docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-ubuntu/

*Result*: "**Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found**".

Reference to similar thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092353/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found).

***Attempt #2***

Tried a simplify my steps and tried this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04

*Result*: Mongo status is **Active: failed (Result: exit-code)**

Reference to similar thread: [Mongodb don't start on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081720/mongodb-dont-start-on-ubuntu-18-04)

***Attempt #3***

Uninstalling and trying this:
[Apt-get fails on 16.04 or 18.04 installing mongodb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842592/apt-get-fails-on-16-04-or-18-04-installing-mongodb/842599#842599)

*Result*:

[image]

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

I did almost the exact same thing (mongodb on Ubuntu 18.04, following the Digital Ocean instructions), and it worked fine for me.
Try using `apt` instead of `apt-get`, and try installing `mongodb` and not `mongodb-org`:

`apt update ; apt install mongodb`

Which for me created the `mongodb.service` and NOT `mongod.service` (note the lack of "b" in the second).

```
techops$ systemctl status mongodb.service
* mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-02-15 11:48:32 EST; 5h 9min ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
 Main PID: 4136 (mongod)
    Tasks: 23 (limit: 4665)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           `-4136 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Feb 15 11:48:32 techops systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
```

Note that the service is called `mongodb` even though the executable is `mongod`.