# Can't start mongod from systemctl

Tags: 18.04, systemd, services, mongodb

I've tried to install MongoDB 5.0 Community edition on Ubuntu 18.04 from the Official doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Everything went fine until I tried to run mongod service:

```bsh
$ systemctl start mongod

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status mongod.service' for details.
```

I tried to gather infos:

```
$ systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$ sudo systemd-analyze verify mongod.service
mongod.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
mongod.service: Failed to create mongod.service/start: Unit mongod.service is not loaded properly: Argument invalide.
Attempted to remove disk file system, and we can't allow that.
```

If I try to enable the service instead, I have the following message:

```bsh
$ systemctl enable mongod.service
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

Indeed, if I read the output from `systemctl list-unit-files`, the mongod service is flagged as `static`.

Here's my `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` contents (automatically written by installing mongodb):

```bsh
  GNU nano 2.9.3                       /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service                                 

[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `/var/log/mongodb/` folder is empty though.

Note that I had a previous versions of MongoDB installed, so I ran through the steps on this post:[Apt-get fails on 16.04 or 18.04 installing mongodb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842592/apt-get-fails-on-16-04-or-18-04-installing-mongodb)

And I tried to installed MongoDB 4.2 after that. And the issue persists.

It is indeed installed though, as I can see its version:

```bsh
db version v4.2.18
git version: f65ce5e25c0b26a00d091a4d24eec1a8b3a4c016
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

What do these systemctl errors mean? What should I try to do?
Thank you for reading.

EDIT: Note that I need to run the `mongod` command through `sudo` to have it working from the terminal.

So I tested to modify the `mongod.service` file in two waYS:

- First with `User=root`, `Group=root`
- Then by adding `mongodb` to my sudo group and using:

```bsh
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=sudo /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Both resulted in the same error: `Invalid argument`

Comment: Follow the installation steps for Ubuntu 20.04 and MongoDB 5.0 for your 18.04 LTS installation: https://askubuntu.com/a/842599/231142  I just did it and it worked just fine for my 18.04 LTS VM install I have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt-get fails on 16.04 or 18.04 installing mongodb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842592/apt-get-fails-on-16-04-or-18-04-installing-mongodb)  Adding this here because the answer(s) should help you.

Comment: Sorry @Terrance, that's the steps I followed, but I just pasted the wrong link in my post (edited now). So no, this didn't help. But thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: You may want to see:  https://serverfault.com/questions/986416/systemctl-complains-about-no-installation-config-but-it-exists  As your service file may not be correct.  Your original error states "Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting." and everything in it is case sensitive as well.

Comment: Your `.service` file is different than mine.  Maybe back yours up to another location and replace it with the one I have below.  A few of the lines are different that I can see between yours and mine.

Comment: I just tried that. Still the same issue.

Thank you for taking time to help me though.

Comment: Everything looks correct then.  Must be something else wrong like systemd might be messed up.  I very highly doubt that it is MongoDB.  Everything required is in the file and yet systemd cannot load it.  Try reinstalling systemd `sudo apt install --reinstall systemd`.  Else, I think you might be looking at a messed up 18.04 installation and you might need to reinstall the OS itself.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I can run it from the CLI though, and I've even switched to a docker container to not mess my OS further. I'm still interested in finding what's wrong though...