# 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install mongodb' not working

Tags: updates, mongodb

I have tried 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install mongodb' neither works.

I want to successfully install mongodb on Ubuntu.

*environment: Ubuntu Version  22.04.1*

I have done the following steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install mongodb` not working,
2. I used `sudo apt-get update`  still not work

I already deleted some of the  `Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80`

I followed the solution on the web, but still facing couldn't download mongodb on Ubuntu

> E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate

Result of sudo apt update

```
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Hit:4 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease               
Ign:6 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease         
Ign:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease         
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                  
Ign:9 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 InRelease         
Ign:10 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease       
Ign:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease       
Ign:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease        
Hit:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release          
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                
Ign:15 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease        
Hit:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 Release          
Hit:18 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release          
Err:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Hit:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease    
Hit:23 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release
Hit:25 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 Release
Get:27 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release [4412 B]
Hit:28 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 Release
Get:30 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Get:31 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0/multiverse arm64 Packages [19.4 kB]
Err:31 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0/multiverse arm64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (19137 != 19448). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 13.35.7.3 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:19448 [weak]
   - SHA512:b0a2d095c3d35504017887747c391ef873c6e69cfd075c216a500899581a742527ea20896e75daa434c8e202d7d986b35614efc4e63691ddb4d8925c34c68476
   - SHA256:bd21ce311d4047515a1a025f93b8d0eaea7a45696f681c5c18a3d8d5f82142a3
   - SHA1:9f870bfdb9aeab6c27ab1ea47b7115d6cabf0250 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:5d9a44e2363a54bfbb2bfba822bdfe0b [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 13 Oct 2022 10:56:48 +0000
Reading package lists... Done   
W: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/4.2/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/4.4/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/4.4/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/jammy/mongodb-org/6.0/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/5.0/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.      

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: OK I can see you have some issues that need to be fixed. You have sources from 3 different versions of Ubuntu in that listing. Remove all non jammy lines. Here from you question is one example of lines that need to be removed from the sources list. Ign:9 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 InRelease The reason it can not find the app is it is looking at old versions of Ubuntu and the app is gone from there. After you clean up the sources list try sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade again, it should be fine no errors. If no errors do the sudo apt get on the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [downloading mongoDB with error "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434992/downloading-mongodb-with-error-e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-bro)  Please don't create a new question.  Edit your original question if you have something else to add.

Comment: MongoDB is not available in the Universe repo for 22.04 (yet).  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mongodb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve the problem. There are others.

Do not skip steps. Stop if you encounter errors.

1. Basic cleanup: Remove all non-Jammy sources from ubuntu.com.
2. Non-Ubuntu cleanup: Remove all sources from repo.mongodb.org.
3. Add the Universe repository: See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) for easy-to-follow instructions.
4. Run `sudo apt update` because you changed your sources. Use the output to confirm that you completed Steps 1-3. If you encounter errors or warnings, then stop. Fix them before proceeding.
5. Install the `mongodb` package from Ubuntu's `universe` repository: `sudo apt install mongodb`