# Installation problem of MongoDB in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dependencies, mongodb, database

This message show in terminal....

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After enter this:

```
~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: You have to use `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: @ArturMeinild I use this command  but error is not solved!

Comment: You will probably want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/842592/apt-get-fails-on-16-04-or-18-04-installing-mongodb/842599#842599

Comment: @Terrance When I try to remove mongoDB, this also show  unmet dependencies error...

Comment: You need to activate the correct repo before you can remove.  It will not let you fix it until you do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)